# Inherited Fields in Sitecore Lucene Content Search

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I have created a Custom Index in Sitecore with which I have indexed a certain section of the Content Tree. Assume that all the items in that tree are created using template A. Lets say there are three fields in A: X Y and Z. X is created directly on A, and Y and Z are inherited from another template B.

When the Lucene Search API on .NET performs a search on the indexed items, for some reason only the values of X appear. The values of Y and Z appear as null.

Is there any restriction on Indexing inherited fields. The Sitecore API however successfully shows all the the three fields.

Comment: Did you check your index with Luke? If so, are the fields filled there?

Comment: Can you check if Template B is on ExcludeTemplate element on your config files?

Comment: Also, check for a few more things - 1. are the fields excluded 2. are the field types excluded for B and C?

Comment: Is "includeallfields" set to true in your config?
...maybe it's best to include your custom index config here..

Comment: Turns out it wasn't an issue with Inheritance but with the name of the Field. The name of the Field is "Text". When I change it to something else like "TestText" it works out correctly. Are there such reserved keywords?  @Gabbar

Comment: It could be. It is best to avoid system names when naming fields/templates/ or pretty much anything in Sitecore.